# Set an idex from the first level of a hierarchical index column, PANDAS

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which is the result of a concatenation of dataframe. I use "keys= " option for the title of each blocks when I export in Excel.

And now I want define the ID2 as an index with ID. (For have a multindex)

I tried to use .resetindex, but it didn't work like I want.

I have:
[image: ![enter image description here]

I want:
[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjVgH.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract your indexes to lists and to create a `MultiIndex` object, and then simply define the index of your DataFrame with this `MultiIndex`. This works on my side (`pandas` imported as `pd`):
Let's assume your initial DataFrame is this one (just a smaller version of what you have):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID2': ['b','c','b'], 'name' : ['tomato', 'pizza', 'kebap']}, index = [1,2,4])
```

Then, we extract the final indices from the index and from the column of the dataframe in order to build a list of tuples, with which you create the multiindex with `pandas.MuliIndex` method:

```
ID2 = df.ID2.to_list()
ID1 = df.index.to_list()
indexes = [(id1, id2) for id1,id2 in zip(ID1,ID2)]
final_indices = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(indexes, names=["Id1", "Id2"])
```

Finally, you redefine your index and you can drop the 'ID2' column:

```
df.index = final_indices
df = df.drop('ID2', axis = 1)
```

This gives the following DataFrame:

[image: Final DataFrame]

Note: I also tried with the `df.reindex` method, but the values of the DataFrame became `NaN`, I do not know why.